# How to fix LaunchImage for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, launchimage

My app, which functioned perfectly on iOS 7, only has one issue since updating to iOS 8. The LaunchImage briefly switches to portrait (since all the images are landscape, it appears distorted) and then returns.

Is there something I need to change to make the LaunchImage compatible?

Comment: Can you say a bit more? You meant that your App supports only landscape and all launch images are thus only landscape but in iOS 8 the supposedly unsupported orientation - portrait - shows the image in portrait briefly?